# How to pass pageable for native query?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I was doing a project and there i had a requirement of using pageable object and recieved page object from JPA.

Does anyone have any idea on how to use this?

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer,Long>{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM WHERE name=?1 AND surname=?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Customer> findAllByNameAndSurname(String name,String surname);
}
```

I want a page List for result fetch from this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data JPA and native queries with pagination is not supported in Spring. According to documentation , Spring Data JPA repositories can be used with native queries and pagination. But, in real life Spring Data JPA (1.10.2.RELEASE) requires some additional fix.

You have to use this if you want pagination support.

```
List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAllByNameAndSurname(name,username);
PagedListHolder<Customer> pages = new PagedListHolder(customers);
pages.setPage(currentPageNumber); //set current page number
pages.setPageSize(pageSize); // set the size of page

pages.getPageList(); // return the list of items(or in your case List<Customer> ) of current page
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    Page<Customer> findAllByNameEqualsAndSurnameEquals(String name, String surname, Pageable pageable);

}
```

I am pretty sure JpaRepository can handle your Pageable parameter.

Also, method name has to be as I mentioned as spring creates queries based on method name (uses reflection).

If you really need to execute NATIVE QUERY you will have to find other solution but I do not recommend the one provided by Dasari Swaroop Kumar as it just queries all objects from database and then kinda filters it in memory.

Also to that native query solution - you can extend your method definition to **additional 2 parameters for page and pageSize** and append them to your native query and leave repository to return plain **List** and then create **PageImpl** object in the layer that calls your **CustomerRepository** object.